# Postgresql crypt fetch password hash and salt

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I didn't find a simple answer on how to fetch the password salt in Postgresql when it was generated with: `crypt($password, gen_salt('bf'))`.
I was looking at some hashes like:

`$2a$06$dcJkzmbYLbPHB2NL5QfVj.D.a7OnEq01l3ZIYJ0IVeNPZ3AIuEpWG`
`$2a$06$2Q3QwDby0xPJSL4CU.izXe1jDFdMDQ1SkSnFE3dWUt2sLeQHq6v76`

and suspected the salt would be the string until the first `.` and the rest would be the password hash? In the first hash there are two `.`. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '.' is just another character in the encoding scheme, no different in meaning than 'Q' or '7', just a different pattern of bits being turned on.

In blowfish case, the first 29 characters is the combination of algorithm identifier and hardness parameter and salt, of which the salt is the last 22.  But there is probably no good reason you need to know this.  It is an opaque object whose internal structure is no one's business but crypt and gen_salt.

Comment: Ok thanks, this means I need to store the salt in a separate column correct? I need to fetch it for some external authentication service.

Comment: When using crypt to verify, you just pass it the whole string and it parses the salt out of it.  No reason to store the salt separately. I would recommend doing it the same way with your external system, if you have the chance to design it that way.

Comment: No sadly not. It is made by another vendor which expects the hash and salt. Thank you anyways!